# trim string before character but still keep the remain part after it

Tags: c#

So I have this string which I have to trim and manipulate a little with it.
My string example:

```
string test = "studentName_123.pdf";
```

Now, what I want to do is somehow extract only the `_123` part and at the end I need to have `studentName.pdf`

What I have tried:

```
string test_extracted = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf("_") )+".pdf";
```

This also works but the thing is that I don't want to add the ".pdf" suffix at the end of the string manually because I can have strings that are not pdf, for ex. `studentName.docx` , `studentName.png`.
So basically I just want the "_123" part removed but still keep the remain part after that.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to first split the name into "not-extension" and "extension", then trim the "not-extension" part, then combine the trimmed not-extension with the extension. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hmm didn't thought of that, sounds good though, I'll give it a try rn.

Comment: @JonSkeet it worked. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
        string test = "studentName_123.pdf";
        string test_extracted = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf("_") )+ test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf("."),test.Length - test.LastIndexOf(".") );
```

Using Remove(int startIndex, int count):

```
        string test = "studentName_123.pdf";
        string test_extracted = test.Remove(test.LastIndexOf("_"), test.LastIndexOf(".") - test.LastIndexOf("_"));
```

Comment: With such an approach, consider `test.Remove( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you mean something like this?

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(test);
string pdfName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(test).Split('_')[0];
string fullName = pdfName + extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what value you will always be replacing in your strings, "_123", to base on your example, just utilize the replace method and replace it with nothing since the method expects two arguments;

```
string test_extracted = test.replace('_123', '');
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the number behind studentName is dynamic too. But this would be much easier if that would actually be the case. Thank you very much, got this one noted.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with a regular expression like this
`(\w*)_.*(\.\w*)` where the first capture group `(\w*)` matches everything before the underscore and the second group `(\.\w*)` matches the file extensions.
Lastly we just have to concat the groups without the stuff inbetween like so:

```cs
string test = "studentName_123.pdf";
var regex = Regex.Match(test, @"(\w*)_.*(\.\w*)");
string newString = regex.Groups[1].Value + regex.Groups[2].Value;
```